# Not able to override cookie

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies, filter, thread-local

I am using **Servlet Filter** to intercept request which has cookies present and then trying to override specific cookie value using ThreadLocal.

But the overridden value is not getting reflected. Also, it is not able to add a new cookie when tried. Couldn't able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

**Controller Class** has two get endpoints. With cookie endpoint I am trying to add a cookie in the response, to intercept and test it when I hit override endpoint afterwards.

```java
@RestController
public class FilterController {
    
    @Autowired
    AlphaCookie alphaCookie;
    
    @Autowired
    AlphaCookieFilter alphaCookieFilter;
    
    @GetMapping("override") // testing endpoint for overriding cookie
    public String cookieTest() {
        this.alphaCookieFilter.persist(new AlphaCookie("newValue"));
        return "Cookie Overriden, { AlphaCookie: newValue }";
    }
    
        
    @GetMapping("cookie")   // to add cookie for testing
    public String addCookieToBrowser(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("AlphaCookie", "oldValue");
        cookie.setMaxAge(3600);
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
        return "Cookie added, { AlphaCookie: old }";
    }
}
```

**Filter** to intercept the request and check for the specific cookie, also override the cookie

```java
@Component("alphaCookieFilter")
public class AlphaCookieFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    public static final ThreadLocal<HttpServletResponse> RESPONSE_HOLDER  = new ThreadLocal<>();
    

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        RESPONSE_HOLDER.set((HttpServletResponse) response);
        
        String activeCookie = null;
        
        if (httpServletRequest.getCookies() != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie: httpServletRequest.getCookies()) {
                if ("AlphaCookie".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    activeCookie = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        
        this.applicationContext.getBean("alphaCookie", AlphaCookie.class)
                               .override(new AlphaCookie(activeCookie));
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        RESPONSE_HOLDER.remove();
    }
    
    public void persist(AlphaCookie alphaCookie) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("AlphaCookie", alphaCookie.getActiveCookie());
        cookie.setDomain("code.org");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        RESPONSE_HOLDER.get().addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

**POJO** to store the cookie value

```java
@Component("alphaCookie")
public class AlphaCookie implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String activeCookie;

    public AlphaCookie() {
        super();
    }

    public AlphaCookie(String activeCookie) {
        this();
        this.activeCookie = activeCookie;
    }


    public void override(AlphaCookie alphaCookie) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.activeCookie = alphaCookie.activeCookie;
        }
    }

    public String getActiveCookie() {
        return this.activeCookie;
    }
}
```

On **debugging** I found below properites are not allowing me to override the cookie value.

```java
cookie.setDomain("code.org");
cookie.setSecure(true);
```

---------**Resolved**-----------

For local testing

1. We should always set the domain name to localhost
2. set cookie.setSecure to false as localhost is not secure protocol (not HTTPS)

Comment: Could you please add your answer as a separate answer rather than keeping it as a part of the question itself? In that way, others can be benefitted greatly.